# Key error in biopython while creating motif

Tags: biopython

I am trying generate a weblogo for the protein sequences provided. The following is my code:

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio import motifs
from Bio.Alphabet import generic_protein

instances = [Seq("RWST"),
              Seq("RTAG"),
              Seq("RQGC"),
              Seq("RMAA"),
             ]


m = motifs.create(instances)
m.weblogo("mymotif.png")
```

I get the following error:

```
counts[letter][position] += 1
KeyError: 'R'
```

---

Full stack trace:

```
<ipython-input-3-ee8922743152> in <module>()
     10 
     11 
---> 12 m = motifs.create(instances)
     13 m.weblogo("mymotif.png")

lib/site-packages/Bio/motifs/__init__.py in create(instances, alphabet)
     21 def create(instances, alphabet=None):
     22     instances = Instances(instances, alphabet)
---> 23     return Motif(instances=instances, alphabet=alphabet)
     24 
     25 

lib/site-packages/Bio/motifs/__init__.py in __init__(self, alphabet, instances, counts)
    236             self.instances = instances
    237             alphabet = self.instances.alphabet
--> 238             counts = self.instances.count()
    239             self.counts = matrix.FrequencyPositionMatrix(alphabet, counts)
    240             self.length = self.counts.length

lib/site-packages/Bio/motifs/__init__.py in count(self)
    192         for instance in self:
    193             for position, letter in enumerate(instance):
--> 194                 counts[letter][position] += 1
    195         return counts
    196 

KeyError: 'R'
```

Comment: Please provide full code. this snippet doesn't explain annything

Comment: HI J, Thanks. I have provided the full code and thats the complete one. I wanted to generate a weblogo..

Comment: do you know what GATC in bio? sorry i am not familiar with any DNA structure but issue seems to be related to GATC

Comment: unambiguous_dna_letters = "GATC" do you know what it is?
Problem is Seq('RWST') 
it allows only letter with GATC
 counts[letter][position] += 1
KeyError: 'R'
it means it looks for counts['R'][0] which doesnt exists.

Comment: Please provide a full traceback of the error.

Comment: GATC are the nucleotide bases... here i wanted the program to accept the amino acid to create weblogo

Comment: I added the traceback of the error as requested by @tripleee. Sam, please have a look if you got the same error.

Answer (score 3):

`Motif` takes an `alphabet` as a keyword (named) argument, so does `motifs.create`. If there is none, BioPython assumes the sequence is a DNA and in your case `R` is not found in the alphabet.
For your example you would need to use `IUPAC.protein` to make it work.

Note: BioPython uses `letters` internally to see which characters are available, `genericProtein` has no letters.

```
from Bio import motifs
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
from Bio.Seq import Seq

instances = [Seq("RWST", IUPAC.protein),
             Seq("RTAG", IUPAC.protein),
             Seq("RQGC", IUPAC.protein),
             Seq("RMAA", IUPAC.protein),
            ]

m = motifs.create(instances, IUPAC.protein)
m.weblogo("mymotif.png")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Peter. Can you help in how to pass the xaxis label in the image

Comment: @Sam All the parameters can be added as keyword arguments: http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.motifs.Motif-class.html#weblogo ,e.g. m.weblogo("mymotif.png", xaxis_label='some text')